# Don’t understand this return type?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I’m reading some code my teacher gave me and I don’t quite understand one specific line of code. The function returns an int&.

```
return (*(Vector *)this)[i];
```

this return statement is in an operator overload of “[]”. There is also another operator overload of [] that is defined in the base class of “this”. The base class is a defined class “Vector”. I don’t understand this line of code.

Comment: 1) type conversation const pointer @this to Vector*
2) dereferencing a pointer  
3) get it's value by int& operator[](int indx)

Comment: First cast `this` into `Vector*` - perfectly legal operation since the class derives from Vector. Then you dereference it via * operator, and in the end you apply the [] operator of Vector.

Comment: I wonder what the difference between `Vector` and the derived classes's `[]` operator is.

Comment: A better way to do this, that should be easier to understand is `return static_cast<Vector&>(*this)[i];`.  It makes it clear that you want `*this` to be treated as a `Vector&` and you call `[]` on that.

Comment: Tell your teacher to stop using C style casts.

Comment: If all the derived version does is call the base one, there's really no reason to re-define it at all. That line is basically the same as `this->Vector::operator[](i)` (except this version is type safe), which just picks an explicit version of `operator[]` and calls it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt, simplify.

First step:

```
return (*(Vector *)this)[i];
```

can be

```
Vector* ptr = (Vector*)this;
return (*ptr)[i];
```

Second step:

```
return (*ptr)[i];
```

can be

```
Vector& ref = *ptr;
return ref[i];
```

Both simplifications put together, the line

```
return (*(Vector *)this)[i];
```

is equivalent to

```
Vector* ptr = (Vector*)this;
Vector& ref = *ptr;
return ref[i];
```

When the member function is a `const` member function, `this` is of type `Vector const* const`.

The first line removes the `const`-ness of the object pointer.
The second line dereferences the pointer.
The last line returns the `i`-th element of the object.

Answer (score 0):

> I don’t understand this line of code.
>
> ```
> return (*(Vector *)this)[i];
> ```

Assuming `T` is a type, `T*` is the type "pointer to `T`". Thus given that `Vector` is a type, `Vector*` is a pointer to `Vector`.

`this` is a special name which is a pointer to the object argument of a member function.

`(T)expr` is an explicit type conversion. It performs one or combination of static cast, reinterpret cast or const cast on the expression, converting the value to the type `T`. In the expression `(Vector *)this`, the `this` pointer is converted to the type `Vector*`. Given that `Vector` is a base class, this is a static cast, and more specifically, an up cast because we are casting up in the inheritance hierarchy.

The unary operator `*` in `*expr` is the indirection operator. It indirects through the pointer (in this case) operand and results in an lvalue of the pointed object. Thus, `*(Vector *)this` will be an lvalue of type `Vector` that is the base class sub object of `this`.

`expr[index]` is the subscript operator. Thus, `(*(Vector *)this)[i]` invokes the subscript operator of the base class on `this` object.

Finally, `return expr;` statement jumps out of the function, and returns the value of the expression to the caller. Thus, `return (*(Vector *)this)[i];` returns the result of the base class' subscript operator.